# e2label: sending ioctl 127c to a partition! in /var/messages

Tags: virtual-machine, debian, logging, ioctl

I'm currently trying to setup a debain (2.6.32-5-amd64/Debian 2.6.32-41squeeze2) webserver on a virtual host machine. Taking a look at my log messages I found the following message in /var/messages (4 messages every 5 minutes):

```
(...) e2label: sending ioctl 127c to a partition!
```

I tried to find some information about this message, but couldn't find any details.
Could anybody tell me why this message is logged and how i could get rid of the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/1/26/432 - it is a warning message that according to Linus himself (second message in thread) will be disabled in then future, now probably current, kernels. The discussion above concerns only 3.x kernels, but perhaps the patch had been incorporated in the 2.6.32 branch as well. In any way, it gives clues on what the message is related to.

If you don't see any symptoms other than the line in the log, you can probably ignore it. It is most probably fixed as per above thread with a newer kernel version than yours.

To find more information: search for

```
"sending ioctl" "to a partition!"
```